# Keeping only some rows of a matrix using one column as choice-maker in R

Tags: r, matrix, selection, rows

I have a matrix in R and I would like to keep only some rows of it according to a column. For example, if I have the matrix A shown here

```
1 2 5 6 8 
1 3 4 5 7
8 8 6 7 7
9 8 8 5 4
0 2 3 4 5
```

I would like to be able to keep only the rows of A for which the last column is 7 or 4, i.e. obtaining a matrix B :

```
1 3 4 5 7
8 8 6 7 7
9 8 8 5 4
```

How can I do so efficiently?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%in%` for multiple values

```
 A[A[,ncol(A)] %in% c(7,4),]
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    1    3    4    5    7
 #[2,]    8    8    6    7    7
 #[3,]    9    8    8    5    4
```

Or if we are using a "data.frame", it could be converted to "data.table" (`setDT`), set the concerned column as "key" (`setkey`) and subset the dataset.

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(as.data.frame(A)), V5)[J(c(7,4))]
 #   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 #1:  1  3  4  5  7
 #2:  8  8  6  7  7
 #3:  9  8  8  5  4
```